# Why doesn't my jQ code work?

Tags: jquery, html, css

So, first I linked script and css:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css" type="text/css">
            <script type='text/javascript' src='script.js'></script> (my script)
            <script type='text/javascript' src='code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js'></script> (jQ)
```

Next I created a div and wrote the script for it:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#div1').click(function(){
        $(this).fadeOut('fast');
    });
});
```

And nothing happened.

Comment: Could you provide a jsfiddle.net?

Comment: Everything works there. http://jsfiddle.net/o7dqagvz/

Comment: Always check console of your browser if there are any errors. If there is any error your js code doesn't work.

Comment: "ReferenceError: $ is not defined" WHAT?!

Comment: I did everything what has been told me here. Nothing works. '//[..]' too.

Comment: probably because you call it jQ..  It doesn't like to be called that way..

Comment: If combining the order and the `//`  which should look like:  `<script type='text/javascript' src='script.js'></script><script type='text/javascript' src='//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js'></script>`, still results a `$ not defined`. Then you most likely open it without a web server.  So try to change it to  `<script type='text/javascript' src='script.js'></script><script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js'></script>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is error :

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js'></script> /* you don't have this file */
<script type='text/javascript' src='script.js'></script>
```

Change to this:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js'></script> /* add this */
<script type='text/javascript' src='script.js'></script>
```

Comment: are your css and js files in same directory as html file?

Comment: Yes, css has been linked properly, I tried copy-paste jQ (from code.jquery[...]) script to file too.

Comment: do you have live example, so we can see whole code.

Comment: Here is your link: https://www.dropbox.com/s/velxk8ol3ekat0q/test%20script.rar?dl=0

Comment: I go to jquery page and link jquery js file from their site. file was on `http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js` link. you give wrong link in your code. Don't forget to upwote my answer.

Comment: @Nicolas Both `http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js`  and `http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js` are valid.  So if you tried the `http://` you might have done something else wrong before.

Answer (score 0):

Link your script.js file after jQuery file.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css" type="text/css">
     <script type='text/javascript' src='code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js'></script>// (jQ)
     <script type='text/javascript' src='script.js'></script> //(my script)
```

Answer (score 0):

You first need to load the Jquery library before loading your own script.
Do it this way:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css" type="text/css">
<script type='text/javascript' src='code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js'></script>// (jQ)
<script type='text/javascript' src='script.js'></script> //(my script)
```